# How can my object be notified when its sheet is displayed?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow

My Cocoa app displays a sheet which needs to do some setup when it's about to be displayed. I believe that the correct place to put the setup code is in a delegate method which is called when the sheet is displayed. Which object should be the delegator? Which delegate method should I implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the NSWindowDelegate method, windowWillBeginSheet: to do your setup.  Probably, the delegate should be in your window or window controller class if you have one of them, otherwise in the app delegate.